Android Studio - No device selected
Iam coding an flutter app in Mac. I am using Android Studio for development.
I am trying to connect actual android device. I dont find the device to run the app in there. I always get "No device selected". I tried the options mentioned here (below), but still no luck. I dont think there is issue with USB, i am able to copy the files from mobile to mac.

Enable Developer mode in device
Enable USB debugging in device
USB preference have it as "File Transfer".
Downloaded Android File Transfer.

No luck. I am able to see this in the Device manager (screen shots below). Can anyone guide me on how to fix this.
Device: Moto e (Android 10).
Android Studio version: 2024.1.1
Any help here will be greatly appreciated.



Thanks,
SP

Have you enabled developer mode on the phone and enabled debugging?

Yup. Enabled all these. 1. Enable Developer mode in device
2. Enable USB debugging in device
3. USB preference have it as "File Transfer".
4. Downloaded Android File Transfer in mac. Stuck in this for last 2 days, without much progress.

USB file transfer mode is independent of ADB and will not be used by Android Studio. Thus it doesn't matter if it is active or not for AS development. What happens if you open the device drop-down menu shown on your first screenshot?

@Robert added the screen shot as third image (to original post). Also notice "Flutter devices", dosen't list android phone. I am able to detect iPhone, its just android phone i am having issues with.

Can you post flutter doctor -v?

Try to use another usb cable.

Was able to fix the issue. It was unable to locate android SDK.
The following command added the sdk location "flutter config --android-sdk /path/to/sdk".
You can get the path of SDK from Settings --> Languages & Frame works --> Android SDK --> Android SDK Location.
Thanks for all the help

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
